# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwings' when trying to run a Python script out of a VBA macro in Excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I have this Python module called ***"RapidAPI_Invest_FX_Lista_Pares_POST_Req.py"*** that fetches out of RapidAPI POST method an updated list of available foreign exchange currency pairs from Investing.com, as follows:

```
import xlwings as xw
import requests
import json

def FX_Lista_Pares():
    # Reference Excel file:
    FinMkt = xw.Book("""FinMkt.xlsm""")

    # Reference API info worksheet:
    wsAPIURL = FinMkt.sheets["""API URL"""]
    wsAPIheaders = FinMkt.sheets["""API Headers"""]

    # Pull URL from API info worksheet:
    url = wsAPIURL.range("E26").value

    # Pull credentials from API info worksheet:
    keyHeader = wsAPIheaders.range("B8").value
    key = wsAPIheaders.range("C8").value
    hostHeader = wsAPIheaders.range("B9").value
    host = wsAPIheaders.range("C9").value

    # RapidAPI content type (when required), key and host headers:
    headers = {
        keyHeader: key,
        hostHeader: host
        }

    # Fetch POST method endpoint data and return in JSON format:
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()

    # Serializing data into JSON:
    json_object = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

    # Writing to sample.json
    with open("""RapidAPI Investing POST Output/FX_Lista_Pares.json""", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(json_object)
```

Once run, the above code then updates the ***"FX_Lista_Pares.json"*** file saved under its respective designated sub-folder.

I then developed a PQ query within Excel that loads and transforms the mentioned JSON file and turn it into an Excel table as pictured below:

[image]

Since I intend to distribute this file to a host of different users with zero coding knowledge, I will do so along a preset xlwings installation file and macro-enabled so VBA codes can be triggered to run the respective Python script that will update such list with the push of a button (the button **"Atualizar lista de moedas"** pictured above for that matter).

And following xlwings' standard process, I wrote within a VBA module the following code so it's assigned to the above mentioned button:

```
Sub FX_Lista_Pares_POST()

    RunPython ("import RapidAPI_Invest_FX_Lista_Pares_POST_Req; RapidAPI_Invest_FX_Lista_Pares_POST_Req.FX_Lista_Pares()")
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - FX_Lista_Pares_Post_Req").Refresh
    Range("A4").Select

End Sub
```

The problem is that every time I attempt to run the code by clicking the button it returns the folowing error message right out of the gate:

[image]

I currently run Python under Anaconda environment via VS Code, and there I have all required modules installed (including xlwings) so this Python script runs just fine.

Since xlwings is supposed to run Python out of virtual environment by default so other users with no pre-installed Anaconda environment can run it straight out of the box, I checked by firing up the
***"RapidAPI_Invest_FX_Lista_Pares_POST_Req.py"*** file straight out of File Explorer, and realized that the line of code that pertains to the xlwings module import gets underscored in yellow as if it's **NOT** pip installed on Windows VE:

But the thing is that xlwings is already installed on my machine. So much so that when I run a new **'pip install xlwings'** as means of troubleshooting the issue Powershell will just return messages saying the requirement is already satisfied!

[image]

I also have another instance of Python 3.10.6 installed outside of Anaconda and have its PYTHONPATH specified on xlwings' toolbar.

[image]

I've literally exhausted all troubleshooting tips I could find around the web to fix this issue but to no avail. Could anyone please shed a light on this one?

Thanks in advance,

Leonardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the previously set VBA code by the one below and it did the trick.

```
Sub FX_Lista_Pares_POST()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExePath As String, PythonScriptPath As String
ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExePath = """%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"""
    PythonScriptPath = """%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Jobs\Consulting\Data BI\Cases\FinData\FinMkt\RapidAPI_Invest_FX_Lista_Pares_POST_Req.py"""

    objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath

    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - FX_Lista_Pares_POST_Req(1)").Refresh
    Range("A4").Select

End Sub
```

I attempted to solve this issue by using this same VBA script, but I had done so with its scope restricted within a respective worksheet, and that's probably the reason the issue kept persisting. Now I have done it within a module and everything works just fine.